# Finding dead electric wire underground

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have an abandoned fountain next to my house. A while back, the previous owner told me there is a dead wire underground that used to power the pump. The pump was removed and the wire buried.

I'm thinking about restoring the fountain. I dug around the fountain 2 ft deep and don't see anything. I know it could be buried deeper 3-4 ft. My questions are: Is it possible to find a dead wire using some sort of fancy equipment? Do professional electricians have the means to do it?

I saw this on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2NeGA7Q7Mo But I'm not sure if something like this works for dead wires (not live big cables).

Please advice

Comment: Can you find the other end of the wire (by the power source)? Borrow or rent a metal detector to locate the end near the house. If you can find one end, a signal generator could be put on that end and the path of the wire traced. There are companies that could do that. I doubt it is 3 or 4 ft deep unless you are in a cold climate where people are used to digging deep trenches for water pipes. Maybe a metal detector would

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That side of the house has a concrete sidewalk all around and the wire must go under it. I forgot to add that I used metal detector that didn't find anything (but it's spec says depth 10 inch) so maybe I need more powerful one. Does the signal generator needs to be physically connected to the wire or just placed in its proximity? The fountain is facing one corner of the house so my guess is that the wire is along that corner.

Comment: I am sure that the signal generator has to be physically connected to the conductor being traced. The receiver of course gets the signal wirelessly.

Comment: To answer your second question, yes professional electricians have this equipment.  Maybe not the really small mom and pop shops, but an average sized company with a service dept certainly will.

Comment: It appears that some equipment can induce a cable to emit a signal without having the signal generator directly physically connected to the cable, but this is surely less sensitive that having the signal generator directly connected to the conductor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I'd just plan to make a new trench and run new wire. Here's why

1. It sounds like a previous DIY project, which likely means it wasn't done correctly. Common problems with this are they used NM wire instead of UF, and they didn't bury it deep enough (needs to be at least 12" by code)
2. The previous wire might not work. If they used NM, there's a good chance it's got some damage by now. Even if not, the ends might be damaged after being buried exposed, and trying to splice in an outdoor setting is a pain. Just avoid the problems and run new wire.
3. Add conduit. It's cheap, it better protects the wire, and it's neater.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! One thing that worries me (in case it was a sloppy job) that the wire was not buried properly or disconnected from the power box. I do have couple light switches in the house that seems to do nothing. What is the worst case scenario if it gets energized some how? Will it just be grounded and pose no problem? Or pop the breaker? What if the ground around it get wet? Sorry I wish I knew my physics better.

Comment: Buy a voltage detector. They can tell you if a wire is live or not. And even if they didn't bury it well, my bet is the connection into the house is above grade. Check for hidden boxes and/or conduit

Answer (score 0):

Just as everyone has said yes you can find someone to locate the underground. It's been my experience that this has never been a cost effective solution. Unless there is a big reason why you can't retrench and reinstall a new circuit. Then I would go that route.